# How to keep text static

Tags: html, css

I added a media query for mobile view. When the max-width is met, the  element within shifts. I want the text to remain as it was in both the tablet and desktop view. Any suggestions on how i could resole this slight issue will be very much appreciate.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG07s.png

```
    h1 {text-align: center;
        color: black;
    }
    
    .box1,
    .box2,
    .box3 {
        margin-top: 30px;
        width: 360px;
        display: inline-block;
        color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        margin-left: 30px;
        background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
    }
    
    .box1 h2,
    .box2 h2,
    .box3 h2 {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    /*The below has been configured for tablet view) */
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
        .box1,
        .box2 {
            width: 39%;
        }
        .box2 {
            clear: right;
        }
        .box3 {
            width: 83%;
        }
    }

    /*The below has been configured for mobile view*/
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .box1,
        .box2,
        .box3 {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 50%;
        }
    }
</style>
```

## Menu

```
<div class="box1">
    <h2>Chicken</h2>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer non sagittis ex. Aenean tempor tortor nec dui fringilla, eu elementum ligula pulvinar. Nam at aliquet felis. Aliquam rhoncus finibus neque, sed venenatis dolor efficitur in. Praesent ex lectus, viverra ut consequat et, congue ac urna. Pellentesque auctor metus non dolor ornare luctus. Duis sit amet pellentesque diam. Aenean ac lorem turpis. Etiam neque arcu, euismod vitae quam sit amet.</span>
</div>enter code here
<div class="box2">
    <h2>Beef</h2>
    <span>Donec scelerisque felis erat, eget fringilla quam molestie eget. Morbi vestibulum semper tellus, id viverra libero consequat eget. Pellentesque a nisi vel dui malesuada pharetra vel ac nisl. Etiam ut nulla lacinia, sodales mi vitae, pulvinar turpis. Nulla sodales enim quis arcu dapibus, non lacinia leo mollis. Aliquam rutrum lacus quis purus dapibus, vehicula tristique sapien tincidunt. Sed molestie velit et purus convallis cursus. Duis scelerisque.</span>
</div>
<div class="box3">
    <h2>Sushi</h2>
    <span>Etiam maximus erat non orci consequat, quis faucibus eros vulputate. Etiam molestie sollicitudin est et commodo. Maecenas volutpat faucibus faucibus. Donec lobortis vulputate tincidunt. Duis eget odio tincidunt, vehicula diam sed, vulputate risus. Ut libero ex, dictum at justo vitae, ullamcorper laoreet neque. Morbi gravida sollicitudin ullamcorper. Etiam ccumsanenter code hereluctus consequat. Etiam `enter code here`eleifend faucibus augue quis pellentesque. Morbi hendrerit, ex sit.</span>
</div>
```

Snippit:

```css
h1 {text-align: center;
        color: black;
    }
    
    .box1,
    .box2,
    .box3 {
        margin-top: 30px;
        width: 360px;
        display: inline-block;
        color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        margin-left: 30px;
        background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
    }
    
    .box1 h2,
    .box2 h2,
    .box3 h2 {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    /*The below has been configured for tablet view) */
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
        .box1,
        .box2 {
            width: 39%;
        }
        .box2 {
            clear: right;
        }
        .box3 {
            width: 83%;
        }
    }

    /*The below has been configured for mobile view*/
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .box1,
        .box2,
        .box3 {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 50%;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="box1">
    <h2>Chicken</h2>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer non sagittis ex. Aenean tempor tortor nec dui fringilla, eu elementum ligula pulvinar. Nam at aliquet felis. Aliquam rhoncus finibus neque, sed venenatis dolor efficitur in. Praesent ex lectus, viverra ut consequat et, congue ac urna. Pellentesque auctor metus non dolor ornare luctus. Duis sit amet pellentesque diam. Aenean ac lorem turpis. Etiam neque arcu, euismod vitae quam sit amet.</span>
</div>
<div class="box2">
    <h2>Beef</h2>
    <span>Donec scelerisque felis erat, eget fringilla quam molestie eget. Morbi vestibulum semper tellus, id viverra libero consequat eget. Pellentesque a nisi vel dui malesuada pharetra vel ac nisl. Etiam ut nulla lacinia, sodales mi vitae, pulvinar turpis. Nulla sodales enim quis arcu dapibus, non lacinia leo mollis. Aliquam rutrum lacus quis purus dapibus, vehicula tristique sapien tincidunt. Sed molestie velit et purus convallis cursus. Duis scelerisque.</span>
</div>
<div class="box3">
    <h2>Sushi</h2>
    <span>Etiam maximus erat non orci consequat, quis faucibus eros vulputate. Etiam molestie sollicitudin est et commodo. Maecenas volutpat faucibus faucibus. Donec lobortis vulputate tincidunt. Duis eget odio tincidunt, vehicula diam sed, vulputate risus. Ut libero ex, dictum at justo vitae, ullamcorper laoreet neque. Morbi gravida sollicitudin ullamcorper. Etiam ccumsanenter code hereluctus consequat. Etiam `enter code here`eleifend faucibus augue quis pellentesque. Morbi hendrerit, ex sit.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying you wish to retain the same aspect ratio of the box containing your text when in mobile view? So the text has the same line breaks, etc...

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean when you say you want the text to stay the same? The purpose of a media query is to change the layout, not to keep it the same.

Comment: Hi dale. The first comment you made regarding the aspect ratio. At the moment, everything just shifts around and looks awkward. Kindly reference the link I attached for a clear picture of what's happening